# How to merge values of array into comma seperated string of similar keys of array

Tags: php, arrays

```
I have this array.

$test['color'][0] = "red";
$test['color'][1] = "blue";
$test['color'][2] = "black";
$test['plug'][3] = "US";
$test['plug'][4] = "UK";
```

i am trying to achieve this from above array.

```
$test2['color'] = "red,blue,black"; 
$test2['plug'] = "US,UK";
```

What would be the best logic to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a little logic and a few PHP functions quite nicely:

```
<?php

    $array['color'][0] = "red";
    $array['color'][1] = "blue";
    $array['color'][2] = "black";
    $array['plug'][3] = "US";
    $array['plug'][4] = "UK";
    $test2=array();
    foreach($array as $key=>$val)
    {
        $test2[$key]=implode(',',$val);
    }

    print_r($test2);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [color] => red,blue,black
    [plug] => US,UK
)
```

Edit: First answer was wrong and overly complicated. This is a one control structure solution.

Comment: Thank Fluffeh. what is the use of $keys array?

Comment: @Semicolon What keys array? In the original answer? Goodness knows, have had way too much wine today hehe. I looked back at the answer I wrote and pretty much facepalmed - hence the edit :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$test2['color'] = implode(',', $test['color']);
$test2['plug'] = implode(',', $test['plug']);

print_r($test2);
```